# Prove line-point distance formula in 2D

Tags: linear-algebra

In the case where the line is in 2D and its equation has the general form $ax +by  =c$, the distance $d(B, l)$ from $B = (x_0, y_0)$ is given by the formula:

$$d(B, l) = \frac{|ax_0+by_0-c|}{\sqrt[]{a^2 + b^2}}$$

How do I go about proving this?
I figured that $B$ could be expressed in terms of the normal vector as $B = f[a, b, c]$, where $f$ is a scalar coefficient but I am not sure whether that leads anywhere. Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: do you want a proof w/out vector?

Comment: Yes of course, that was just that I came up with.

Comment: I will type it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B'(x_1,y_1)$ where $BB'$ is perpendicular to $L:ax_0+by_0+c$.

As $B'$ lay on $L$, $B'= (x_1,-\frac{a}bx_1+\frac{c}b)$ .

As $BB'$ is perpendicular to $L$, product of slope of $L$ and $BB'=-1$. So we have:

$$\frac{-\frac{a}bx_1+\frac{c}b-y_0}{x_1-x_0}=-\frac{b}a$$
$$-\frac{a^2}{b^2}x_1+\frac{ac}{b^2}-\frac{a}by_0=x_1-x_0$$
$$(1+\frac{a^2}{b^2})x_1=x_0-\frac{a}by_0+\frac{ac}{b^2}$$
$$x_1=\frac{b^2x_0-aby_0+ac}{a^2+b^2}$$
$$y_1=\frac{-abx_0+a^2y_0-\frac{ac}{b^2}+\frac{ac}{b^2}+bc}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{-abx_0+a^2y_0+bc}{a^2+b^2}$$

So

\begin{align}
D(B,L)&=\sqrt{(\frac{b^2x_0-aby_0+ac}{a^2+b^2}-x_0)^2+(\frac{-abx_0+a^2y_0+bc}{a^2+b^2}-y_0)^2}\\&=\sqrt{(\frac{-a^2x_0-aby_0+ac}{a^2+b^2})^2+(\frac{-abx_0-b^2y_0+bc}{a^2+b^2})^2}\\&=\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}}\cdot|\frac{-a^2x_0-aby_0+ac}{a^2+b^2}|\\&=\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2}}\cdot|\frac{-a^2x_0-aby_0+ac}{a^2+b^2}|\\&=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a}\cdot|\frac{a^2x_0+aby_0-ac}{a^2+b^2}|\\&=|\frac{ax_0+by_0-c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}| 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your time, that was a very thorough answer and I've learned a lot just by working through it. Could I ask you what exactly happens in the last step of the proof? It seems like the nominator is divided by $(-a)$ and you take the square root of the denominator but I am not sure why it happens.

Comment: I've added the second last step.Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Thanks again for your help.